# Right way to check if user has role in meteor?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm building a CMS and depending on the user `role` they will be able to edit/update/delete/create different areas but filtered by their `role` as in, one user with `role: 'basic role'` can't delete what the user with `role: 'superuser'` can.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
Collection.allow({
  insert: function(userId, collection) {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId, profile: {role: 'admin'}});
  },
  update: function(userId, collection, fields, modifier) {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId, profile: {role: 'admin'}});
  },
  remove: function(userId, collection) {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId, profile: {role: 'admin'}});
  }
});
```

**QUESTION**
Is this the right way to validate users roles? Are there better ways? What are the best practices for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) package. It's quite widely used and even mentioned in the Meteor Docs. In addition to roles, it also supports groups.

Comment: This is the canonical _roles_ package for Meteor.